# spring boot source code for datasource creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm trying to go through spring-boot sources to gain a bit more confidence about its inner workings.

For example:
When you use following properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=as
```

spring boot will try to guess the jdbc driver you need by parsing `spring.datasource.url` property, and look in the classpath for the desired driver.

We can deduce this behaviour by reading Spring documentation:

> You often do not need to specify the driver-class-name, since Spring
>   Boot can deduce it for most databases from the url.
>
> For a pooling DataSource to be created, we need to be able to verify
>   that a valid Driver class is available, so we check for that before
>   doing anything. In other words, if you set
>   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, then that
>   class has to be loadable.

I think the code responsible for that could be found somewhere around [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc).

But I seem not to be able to find it.

Can you help me shed some light on that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JDBC driver class name is governed by the constants in the [`DatabaseDriver` enum](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/36c1c051b8106371d37f8a747cea0e369a8e5c84/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/DatabaseDriver.java#L36). See how this enum is used to understand where the datasource URL property is parsed e.g. in `DataSourceConfiguration` you will find:

```
DatabaseDriver databaseDriver = DatabaseDriver
                .fromJdbcUrl(properties.determineUrl());
```